# Set image for ImageView on another layout

Tags: android, drawable, android-imageview

I am trying to set the background image of an ImageView
 on another layout. The other layout is the table row layout. Here is the code

```
ImageView pdfImage;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.help);

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService
         (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.listlayout, null);
    pdfImage = (ImageView)ll.findViewById(R.id.pdfImage);

    pdfImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pdflogo);
```

The `pdflogo` is not getting set to the image. It is just blank. How can I do this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="50dp">       
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/selfImage" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:background="@drawable/selfhelpnavbar"/>
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/logoImage" android:layout_width="70dp" android:layout_height="46dp" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/mainLogo" android:layout_width="50dp" android:layout_height="46dp" android:background="@drawable/mainlogo" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>
</RelativeLayout> 

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/helpList"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="387dp" >
    </ListView>

<!-- Tab Bar -->
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/helpButton"
        android:layout_width="0.0dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/selfhelptab_selected" 
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:clickable="true"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/eButton"
        android:layout_width="0.0dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/eapservicestab" 
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:clickable="true"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/mailButton"
        android:layout_width="0.0dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/mailtab" 
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:clickable="true"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/gethelpButton"
        android:layout_width="0.0dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/gethelptab" 
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:clickable="true"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/moreButton"
        android:layout_width="0.0dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/moretab" 
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:clickable="true"/>

</LinearLayout></LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
setContentView(R.layout.help);
```

with this statement, you're setting help.xml as your layout to be shown. Later on, you inflate another layout, do something with it's image, but as far as I can see, this layout is neither part of help.xml, nor it is set to be shown via setContentView.

try this:

```
ImageView pdfImage;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService
         (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.listlayout, null);
    pdfImage = (ImageView)ll.findViewById(R.id.pdfImage);

    pdfImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pdflogo);
    setContentView(ll);
```

Comment: If I set the contentView to the layout then my original layout doesn't show up. That `listlayout` is just for my rows in my table. see picture

Comment: please provide help.xml structure

Comment: I have added the xml structure